# How to get the Unique id of the specific view

Tags: android

```
//inflating row  
customView1=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_materialdimension, null);

container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container);
container.addView(customView1, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

//Getting child Count from parent inflated the child  
int child = container.getChildCount();
container.setTag(child + 1);

for (int i = 0; i < child; i++) {
    Log.e("ChildAt", "" + container.getChildAt(i));
    View childView = container.getChildAt(i);
    Log.e("childView ", "childView" + childView);
    TextView tv1=(TextView)childView.findViewById(R.id.txt_parent_plus_id);

    // setting onClickListner to inflated child
    //i want to get unique id when i click on the inflated child**
    tv1.setOnClickListener(handleOnClick(tv1));
}

//i want to get unique id when i click on the inflated child**

View.OnClickListener handleOnClick(final View view) {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("Clicked", "Clicked" + container.getTag());
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Question is not clear plz explain more

Comment: Exactly. Your question is a little unclear. What are you trying to do? Get the Id of the clicked view? Or trying the get the Id of any resource view?

Comment: i have one parent layout with textview1,Edittext1,textview2 and child layout with textview3,editext2,textview4...what i am trying to do when i click on textview2 then childlayout get inflated and now textview4 have it's onclicklistner and when i click on textview4 then new child is going to be inflated below it....and i want the unique id for the previous textview4 child and currently inflated textview4 child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use    **setId()** and **getId()** methods.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < child; i++) {
 Log.e("ChildAt", "" + container.getChildAt(i));
 View childView = container.getChildAt(i);
 TextView tv1=(TextView)childView.findViewById(R.id.txt_parent_plus_id);
 tv1.setId(i);
 }


tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           int id=tv1.getId();
           Log.e("Clicked", "Clicked" + String.valueOf(id)));
        }
    });
```

Comment: getting null pointer exception, first child is inflating but on second child inflation it giving me null pointer exception on this line

Comment: tv1.setId(i);
tv1.setOnClickListener(handleOnClick(tv1));

Comment: you remove that tv1.setOnClickListener(handleOnClick(tv1)); and that place paste above code then check

Comment: for the first child ,i am getting the onclick id as 0, but when i am inflating second child then null pointer is coming ,i edited my code according to you

Comment: when i first time click on the parent then one child with the id is inflating is right but when i second time clicking the parent to get the inflation again then null pointer is coming.